# How do you save multiple tool window layouts in Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio

I arranged my Android Studio IDE tool windows layout to fit 2 screens in a dual monitor setup and saved it as the default. I would also like to save another layout for single screen setup.

Question: Is it possible to save multiple layout configuration for tool windows in Android Studio. If so how?

Thanks,
George

Answer (score 13):

Go to menu window > Store current layout as default

[image]

Comment: Seems like this option only allows 1 layout configuration to be saved and restored. Can it be possible to save multiple configuration?

Answer (score 2):

A bit late to the party, but there is a newer plugin, that works much better imho.
You can define 4 layouts, it can switch layouts immediately, it also (re-)stores the floating state of each panel and so on:

https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/13005-window-layout-manager

Answer (score 0):

There is an IntelliJ IDEA plugin [preserve-layout-plugin](https://github.com/vduseev/preserve-layout-plugin) that allows you to that. It's available in the plugin repository, just search for preserve.

[image: After installing it you can export and import layouts from the window menu]

By default, you need to restart the IDE or open another project in order to load the layout but the following works as well: you import the layout, you store it as default, and then you restore the default layout.

Answer (score 0):

The following method helped me.

1) Run Android Studio as administrator.

2) Now, arrange the tabs as you want.

3) Go to Window->Store current layout as default.

Answer (score 0):

This is something I missed when I started Android development especially after using multiple layout in Unity Editor before this.

However, I found this plugin - "Window Layout Manager" [Link](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/13005-window-layout-manager) which you can also find and install via Android Studio plugins marketplace.

Allows you to arrange different windows/components like terminal, logcat, project explorer etc and save it with a name.

[image: Multiple saved layouts using the plugin]