# Android Studio Tool Window Location Settings (Multiple Monitor)

Tags: android-studio

- Open or Create a project
- Move the tool windows around and resize them
- Close Project
- Create New Project or Open Existing Project (Doesn't Matter)

** Windows are all back to their docked and default location.  I tried exporting the settings but that didn't do it.  I have multiple monitors and it's a pain to move the various windows that I like to see at all times.  I just updated Android studio and it did not fix the problem.   Does anyone know how to save these toolwindow location/settings?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you save multiple tool window layouts in Android Studio?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23475144/how-do-you-save-multiple-tool-window-layouts-in-android-studio)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

See my reply in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23475144/how-do-you-save-multiple-tool-window-layouts-in-android-studio/31016203#31016203).

Go to menu window > Store current layout as default.

[image]